# Display a custom name when the user has no name settle in his account

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, shortcode, username

I'm creating a code that shows the First Name for logged in users, using a shortcode, but I noticed that if the user has no name settle, it will display a blank space. How can I set a custom name to show up  instead of the blank space? Something like this "Hi >No Name<, please settle your name in your account."

Display first name:

```
// show first name if logged in
function colaborador_nome($atts) { if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) { return '&nbsp;'. get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true ); }
 }
add_shortcode('colaborador_nome', 'colaborador_nome');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [ternary comparsion operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to check if `get_user_meta()` function returns blank or non-blank result:

```php
function colaborador_nome($atts) {
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
        return '&nbsp;'. (get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true ) ?: "Hi >No Name<, please settle your name in your account.");
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborador_nome', 'colaborador_nome');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why, but I posted the wrong code. It's the right code now. Please check.

Comment: @21321312 That doesn't make much difference except you should wrap ternary operator with brackets. If you want the full code, here it is.

Comment: Tried it, it results in a syntax error.

Comment: @21321312 It could be only if you copy-pasted this code incorrectly or if you are using PHP version less than 5.3. What is your PHP version?

Comment: I'm on a localhost using PHP Version 7.2.28.

Comment: But I'm using Dreamweaver CS5 for editing the scripts.

Comment: @21321312 Is it Dreamweaver who tells you about syntax error? Or you get it on practice?

Comment: Both dreamweaver and website frontend.

Comment: @21321312 Ok, copy-pasted provided code to live WP instance and checked with `echo do_shortcode('[colaborador_nome]');`. Works as expected, no syntax errors here.

Comment: For me it returns an error, even in the website. Isn't there another workaround or least another formatting?

Comment: @21321312 Sounds weird. Ok, try `return '&nbsp;'. (($username = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true )) ? $username : "Hi >No Name<, please settle your name in your account.");` instead.

Comment: @21321312 Maybe you can copy an error you got with this code and paste it with a comment?

Comment: Your newer code worked. Now I'm trying to understand why the previous code didn't work. Do you have any clue?

Comment: @21321312 As I said, the shorthand form of PHP ternary operator `$a ?: $b` should be supported starting from PHP 5.3. This is a shorter version of `$a ? $a : $b` classic form of ternary operator which is used in the second code example. [Here](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/whats-the-difference-between-null-coalescing-operator-and-ternary-operator-in-php) is a good article on this subject. I tried to find if this can be disabled through the PHP settings, but didn't find any evidence of it. Why the first code didn't work for you is a mystery to me. Can you post a PHP error message?

Comment: I enabled Wordpress debug, but I didn't get any error related to the issue we had here.